# Using the Strategy Design Pattern with Python

Tags: python, strategy-pattern

I work at a place that has multiple projects.  Depending on the project, I want items in a list processed in a certain way.  I thought this problem would lend itself to the Strategy pattern.  However, before committing fully to this pattern, I created a small app to demo how I think the final app would work.

First, I created a Strategy class:

```
import types
import rules.work_on_x

class WorkOnProjectsStrategy:

    def __init__(self, project="default"):
        self.project = project
        self.msg = "{0} is the project.".format(self.project)

        if project == "x":
            self.do_that = types.MethodType(rules.work_on_x.do_that, self)
            self.do_this = types.MethodType(rules.work_on_x.do_this, self)

    def do_that(self):
        print("Do that!")

    def do_this(self):
        print("Do this!")
```

As you see I have some methods that I defined that cause the do_that and do_this methods to behave in a certain way with a project called x.

```
def do_that(self, thing):
    print(self.msg)
    print("Doing that on {0}".format(thing))

def do_this(self, some_thing):
    print(self.msg)
    print("Doing this on {0}".format(some_thing))
```

I then created the client (a simple GUI) that would leverage the strategy class.

```
import os
import sys

from work_on_projects_strategy import WorkOnProjectsStrategy

from PySide2 import QtCore
from PySide2 import QtUiTools
from PySide2 import QtWidgets

class Client(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, ui_file, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        # Load the ui file
        ui_file = QtCore.QFile(ui_file)
        ui_file.open(QtCore.QFile.ReadOnly)
        loader = QtUiTools.QUiLoader()
        self.my_widget = loader.load(ui_file)
        ui_file.close()
        self.my_widget.show()

        # Set up connections
        self.line_edit_input_asset = \
            self.my_widget.findChild(QtCore.QObject, "lineEdit_inputasset")
        self.push_button_execute = \
            self.my_widget.findChild(QtCore.QObject, "pushButton_execute")
        self.push_button_execute.clicked.connect(self.doing_stuff)

    def doing_stuff(self):
        proj = self.line_edit_input_asset.displayText()
        things = ["thing_1", "thing_2"]
        for thing in things:
            strategy = WorkOnProjectsStrategy(proj)
            if thing == "thing_1":
                strategy.do_that(thing)
            elif thing == "thing_2":
                strategy.do_this(thing)

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication()
    client_ui = os.path.join("ui", "demo_client.ui")
    client_tool = Client(client_ui)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Could this design be improved?  I noticed that one issue is I might end up with a big if/else statement in the Strategy class.  This might be easy to understand, but I'm not sure if it is particularly elegant.  The code does work.  Here is the output after putting "x" in the GUI:

```
(MY_ENV) > python .\client.py
x is the project.
Doing that on thing_1
x is the project.
Doing this on thing_2
```

I am surprised this worked.

```
if project == "x":
    self.do_that = types.MethodType(rules.work_on_x.do_that, self)
    self.do_this = types.MethodType(rules.work_on_x.do_this, self)
```

I thought you could only dynamically assign one method to one instance of a class.